# Android: Search Filter for exact match only

Tags: android, listview, search, filter

I'm trying to set up a search filter for my list view table which will only return results which are an **exact** match. I have set up a filter linked to my table layout as follows:

```html
 private class RowFilter extends Filter{

  @Override
  protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
   FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
   
   if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
    
    results.values = data;
    results.count = data.size();
   }
   
   else{
    
    ArrayList<Rows> filterData = new ArrayList<Rows>();
    
    for (Rows r : data) {
     if(r.getTenancy().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
      
      filterData.add(r);
      results.values = filterData;
      results.count = filterData.size();
      
      }else if(r.getAddress().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
       
       filterData.add(r);
      
      }else if(r.getLocation().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
       
       filterData.add(r);
      
      }else if(r.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
       
       filterData.add(r);
      
      } 
    }
    
    results.values=filterData;
    results.count = filterData.size();
    
  
   }
   return results;
  }

  @Override
  protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
    FilterResults results) {
   if(results.count==0){
    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
   }else{if(results.count==1){}
    
    data = (ArrayList<Rows>) results.values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    
   }
  }
    }
}
```

Where if the strings do match the entry, they are added to the final list of published rows.

**I think the problem is** that it is being updated all the time so when I search something that isn't there, it will just show everything that was previously searched, instead of showing an empty table like I want. I know i'm missing something important in my code to make this happen so any help would be incredibly appreciated as I've spent a long time on this.

**This is the code inside main.java,**

```js
EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_query);
  
  editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           
   @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]-Start ["+start+"]-Before["+before+"]-Count["+count+"]");
          
          if(count<before){
          
            adapter.resetData();
           
          }
          
          adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());                           
      }
       
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
              int after) {
           
      }
       
      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      }
  });
```

EDIT: Essentially I only want to be able to see results which **exactly** match my search text, otherwise print no table at all.

Comment: Tell me if you need anymore code and ill post it up ASAP. Thanks guys/girls!!

Comment: I think you have to use String.equalsIgnoreCase(constraint) not startswith